# Accessing files on webserver with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written a Matlab script to perform some analysis on audio samples recorded at different locations. I have a mobile app that records audio and stores it on a web server. Is there a way I can access this file from Matlab as an input to the script? The url and individual file names will be available, I assume there is a Matlab command that uses this information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
str = urlread('http://stackoverflow.com');
```